# Visual Studio support for my own language

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I want to use Visual Studio 2019 Community as an IDE for my own language. Visual Studio can be extended to this, by an extension: for example, there is an extension for Rust syntax highlighting. What is the descriptor language what descripts the syntax of the programming language? I wish an example file what describes the syntax: reserved words, operators, etc. For example, for Pascal, C, C++, assembly, Rust, C#, Python, etc. I want to copy and modify this, to describes my own language. After it, how can I install the support my language?

By the way, I wish create shortkeys for special characters, for example, Alt+A should be insert the character ∀ to the source file what is in my own language.

Comment: See [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview) for how you could integrate your language with VSCode